# How to compare string or int type?

Tags: php

```
if($_GET['choice'] == (int))
```

or

```
if($_GET['choice'] == (string))
```

I got an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All GET parameters are strings. If you want to be certain that it's an integer in the string then you should [sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) it.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the string `$_GET['choice']` may be represented as an integer, use `ctype_digit()`, eg

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['choice'])) {
    // integer
}
```

Comment: `ctype_digit()` will fail on `+` or `-`, which may or may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.  Your example shows CASTING:

```
$var = (int)"15";  // casts the string 15 as an integer
```

If you want to compare if something is an INTEGER, you can use the `is_int()` function in PHP.  There are other operators that will do this for strings, arrays, etc;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: Careful, `is_int()` will never return true for a `$_GET` param